# Huawei router's WebUI is inaccessible

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, domain, console

When I try to log in to my router's [Huawei 4G box from "Orange" A-7FE] WebUI via `192.168.1.1` on my laptop, it shows a `website inaccessible` error due to connection timeout.

- I can log in from other devices, but not this laptop, and I can't ping `192.168.1.1`.  I can access all other websites normally; the only difference with this laptop is it's connected to a work office's network via VPN, using a domain user session, whereas other devices I've tried aren't.

  - I've tried deleting cookies and all IP related information, as well as different browsers.
  - I've checked all my proxy, firewall, antivirus configurations and they are not the issue.

What might be the reason for this?

Comment: The issue likely lies with how the VPN connection is routing traffic... disconnect from the VPN and if you can access the router's WebUI, that's the issue.  To resolve, you'll need to either manually modify the routing table on the device via a terminal or modify the VPN config settings (if possible).

Comment: For logging into the Huawei Router, try the following:  
Make sure the HUAWEI device is plugged into the Computer, open a Web Browser:
Go to:    http://192.168.8.1    Try this web address

Comment: basic network checks are done with `ping`, `traceroute` (or `tracert` on WIndows) and `route` commands. in your case the tracert will probably show that the traffic to 192.168.1.1 is routed through your VPN connection and the route command output would confirm that the traffic is being pushed through the VPN. and as you noted - the inability to ping on this device while being connected to the VPN and working from all other devices would suggest that the traffic is going another route.....with a slim possibility that outgoing ping to the IP is blocked - I saw a lot of different things :)

Comment: It is as expected the vpn configuration..thank you everyone